# How to change an Editable Region to a Non-Editable Region in my Dreamweaver template

Tags: html, templates, dreamweaver

I’m working in Dreamweaver CS3. I’ve created a template and made my horizontal menu bar an editable region. I realize now that was a bad decision since I want to be able to edit the menu once and not on every page. I want to turn it back into a non editable region.

I’ve tried:

- Modify>Templates>Remove Template Markup (it’s grayed out)
- Modify>Templates>Detach from Template (it’s grayed out)
- I’ve manually removing the markup in the code, yet it still remains editable

I don’t know what else I can do. Is this because it’s a spry menu?

Comment: Not programming-related.

Answer (score 1):

If you've marked a region of your template file as editable and you want to lock it (make it non-editable in template-based documents) again, use the `Remove Template` Markup command.

Click the tab in the upper-left corner of the editable region to select it.

Do one of the following:

1. Select Modify > Templates > Remove Template Markup.
2. Right-click (Windows) or Control‑click (Macintosh), then select Templates > Remove Template Markup.
3. The region is no longer editable.

Answer (score 0):

Once you move something into an editable region in DW, you will have to manually remove it from all child pages.  You can certainly move the code back on the dwt file to an uneditable region, but all child pages will not retroactively edit code or text in the editable region.

This is because DW assumes that anything in an editable region is your content and thus not to be overwritten by changes to the template.  Changes to stuff inside an editable region will be applied to new pages created from the template only.

So, your steps are:

1) Move the menu code back to the uneditable region in the template
2) Do a Find and Replace to remove the code from the editable region in all child pages completely in your entire site
3) Update all child pages so the menu code gets replaced in the uneditable region.